# React do not render new components, new webpack setup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Today I was setting up my first Webpack Bebel React project and I got some strange case here.I don't know why, but every single Component that I make is not recognized by React. I can see it directly in the inspector, and It seems like it's not getting compiled. All standard HTML elements are getting rendered. Even console.log inside of constructor function of a component that I have created is not called. I run Hot mode with webpack -p

Here is my Webpack config:

```
    const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const cssDeveloperLoaders = ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
const cssProduction = ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    loader: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    publicPath: '/dist'
})

const cssConfig = isProduction ? cssProduction : cssDeveloperLoaders

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.jsx'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: cssConfig
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname + '/node_modules/'),
                use: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presents: ['es2015','react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        open: true,
        openPage: ''                    //Fix to webpack version 3.0.0 after removing redirection to /undefined
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'app.css',
            disable: !isProduction,     //So if production is running it will generate file otherwise not
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
    ]
}
```

My .bablerc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react"
    ]
}
```

App.jsx:

```
import './app.scss'

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';


import engine from './engine.jsx'


render(
    <engine/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

engine.jsx

```
import React from 'react';


class engine extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log('Component has been constructed ')
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>xD</div>
        )
    }
}
export default engine;
```

The picture of React Chrome extension.

[image]

Please notice, console.log is not been called.

My html is empty, I see only engine element (Not compiled.)

Any suggestions about this problem?

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="app.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: since you already have a .babelrc file, please remove query: {
                    presents: ['es2015','react']
                } this from your webpack.config.js

Comment: Also replace the babel-loader test condition with this 
test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,

Comment: post your index.html also

Comment: @VivekN I done all you said still the same, my regex is also good, I always used it.

Comment: @VivekN not that it matters much, but I'd use `/\.jsx?$/`

Comment: @YuriRamos I did :)

Comment: @ArturK.Any console errors?

Comment: @VivekN no, there is no errors at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your webpack config file add

   resolve : {
          extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
         }

So that you won't need to import your jsx file with extenstion.

2. Class names should start with Capital letters otherwise methods in react components will not be invoked and also no error will be thrown.

engine.jsx

```
    class Engine extends React.Component{
        constructor(){
            super();
            console.log('Component has been constructed ')
        }
        render(){
            return(
                <div>xD</div>
            )
        }
    }

export default Engine;
```

App.jsx

```
import Engine from './engine'
render(
    <Engine/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Please verify  https://codesandbox.io/s/D9rpvWWG6
Also you can refer https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4695

Comment: Thank you, this was a BIG mistake of mine. You are 100% correct about capital letters. Thank you for pointing that out.  I also added resolve as you said, It works perfect.